# Why BobJenkinsHash function returns range error in this case?

Tags: delphi, lazarus

Under FPC Lazarus, I am using the following function to compute the hash of a string, this is used to save the object in a dictionary:

```
function MyClass.HashCode(): UInt32;
var
  keyStr: string;
begin
  keyStr := KeyToString();
  Result := BobJenkinsHash(keyStr[1], Length(keyStr) * SizeOf(Char), 0);
end;
```

This function sometimes throws an error:

> Project < Name > raised exception class ' RunError(201)' with message:
> Range check error
>
> in file < source > at line < Line >:
> Result := BobJenkinsHash(keyStr[1], Length(keyStr) * SizeOf(Char), 0);

This happens coherently after some usages. I am not sure if some specific strings or number of usages. For example: "Button_logo" seems to raise this error.

I could not find (unfortunately) relevant documentation about this: I found no documentation for FPC and Delphi documentation is (as most of the time) irrelevant.

Comment: Is `keyStr` valid when the error occurs? Or is it empty, perhaps?

Comment: It value is `Button_logo`, but for example `Button_avatar` works. It could be that several calls are required to get to this problem.
I have tested on RadStudio (Delphi) and get the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this applies to FreePascal, but in Delphi the [`BobJenkinsHash()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Defaults.BobJenkinsHash) function (which is deprecated<sup>1</sup>, BTW) returns a *signed* `Integer`:

```
function BobJenkinsHash(const Data; Len, InitData: Integer): Integer;
                                                             ^^^^^^^
```

You are assigning that return value to an *unsigned* `UInt32`. If the function returns a negative value (see [Can result of BobJenkinsHash function be negative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244464/can-result-of-bobjenkinshash-function-be-negative)), you will get a runtime error if you have Range Checking enabled.

<sup>1</sup> this same issue exists for the function's successor in Delphi, [`THashBobJenkins.GetHashValue()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Hash.THashBobJenkins.GetHashValue), too.

So, you can either:

- turn off Range Checking. You can use the [`{$RANGECKECKS ON|OFF}`/`{$R±}`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progsu65.html) compiler directive ([Delphi](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Range_checking))  to disable Range Checking around the assignment of your `UInt32`, eg:

  ```
  function MyClass.HashCode(): UInt32;
  var
    keyStr: string;
  begin
    keyStr := KeyToString();
    {$IFOPT R+} {$RANGECHECKS OFF} {$DEFINE RC_WAS_ON} {$ENDIF}
    // or: {$IFOPT R+} {$R-} {$DEFINE RC_WAS_ON} {$ENDIF}
    // or: {$PUSH} {$R-} (FPC only)
    Result := BobJenkinsHash(PChar(keyStr)^, Length(keyStr) * SizeOf(Char), 0);
    {$IFDEF RC_WAS_ON} {$RANGECHECKS ON} {$UNDEF RC_WAS_ON} {$ENDIF}
    // or: {$IFDEF RC_WAS_ON} {$R+} {$UNDEF RC_WAS_ON} {$ENDIF}
    // or: {$POP} (FPC only)
  end;
  ```
- type-cast the return value of `BobJenkinsHash()` before assigning it to your `UInt32`:

  ```
  function MyClass.HashCode(): UInt32;
  var
    keyStr: string;
  begin
    keyStr := KeyToString();
    Result := UInt32(BobJenkinsHash(PChar(keyStr)^, Length(keyStr) * SizeOf(Char), 0));
  end;
  ```
- change the return type of your `HashCode()` method to `Integer`:

  ```
  function MyClass.HashCode(): Integer;
  var
    keyStr: string;
  begin
    keyStr := KeyToString();
    Result := BobJenkinsHash(PChar(keyStr)^, Length(keyStr) * SizeOf(Char), 0);
  end;
  ```

Comment: Actually it's a good point. I assumed that it was the function itself  triggering that exception, but I might be the return value. I wil test and update/accept in case.

Comment: Another option would be to simply hard cast the return value to UInt32: _Result := UInt32(BobJenkinsHash(PChar(keyStr)^, Length(keyStr) * SizeOf(Char), 0));_ thus eliminating the need to fiddle with the {$R} compiler directive.

Comment: *simply make sure you to turn off Range Checking.* Turning checks of should only be done as a last resort; use the computer to catch your errors. Can't he just change his function result?

Comment: If FPC only, the conditionals can be shorted considerably to {$push} {$R-} ... {$pop}